# Video call issue from remote network using Webrtc

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, angular, webrtc

When two of my systems are in same network then the video call works fine in both systems but when i changed network of any one system then no videos showing for remote video of both the systems. N.B : i am using  stun server and turn Server both , can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

```
async createpeerConnection(connid) {
    this.startwithAudio();
    console.log("createConnection with ID:" + connid);

    this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: "turn:turn.xxx.com:5349",
          username: "test",
          credential: "test123",
        },
        {
          urls: "stun:stun.yyyy.com:5349"
        },
      ]

    });
    debugger
    //this.connection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.iceConfiguration);
    this.connection.onicecandidate = (event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => {
      console.log('onicecandidate event occur');
      if (event.candidate) {
        debugger
        this._serverFn(JSON.stringify({ 'iceCandidate': event.candidate }), connid);
      }
    }
    this.connection.onicecandidateerror = this.handleIceCandidateEventError;
    this.connection.onicegatheringstatechange = this.handleIceGatheringStateChange;
    debugger
    this.connection.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
      console.log("onnegotiationneeded event occur");
      await this.connection.setLocalDescription(await this.connection.createOffer());
      this._serverFn(JSON.stringify({ 'offer': this.connection.localDescription }), connid);
    }
    this.connection.onconnectionstatechange = this.handleIceConnectionStateChangeEvent;
    debugger
    this.connection.ontrack = (event: RTCTrackEvent) => {
      console.log('ontrack event occur');
      if (!this._remoteVideoStreams[connid]) {
        this._remoteVideoStreams[connid] = new MediaStream();
      }
      debugger
      if (!this._remoteAudioStreams[connid])
        this._remoteAudioStreams[connid] = new MediaStream();
      debugger
      if (event.track.kind == 'video') {
        console.log("send video stream");
        this._remoteVideoStreams[connid].getVideoTracks().forEach(t => this._remoteVideoStreams[connid].removeTrack(t));
        this._remoteVideoStreams[connid].addTrack(event.track);
        debugger
        console.log("remote video id:" + 'v_' + connid);
        console.log("video streams:" + this._remoteVideoStreams[connid]);
        this._remoteVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('v_' + connid);
        debugger
        if (this._remoteVideoPlayer != null)
          this._remoteVideoPlayer.srcObject = this._remoteVideoStreams[connid];
        this._remoteVideoTrack = this._remoteVideoStreams[connid].getVideoTracks()[0];
        debugger
        console.log("_remoteVideoTrack other notworkVideo recived", this._remoteVideoTrack);
        this.remoteVideoActive = true;
      }
      else if (event.track.kind == 'audio') {
        console.log("send audio stream");
        this._remoteAudioPlayer = document.getElementById('remoteAudioCtr')
        this._remoteAudioStreams[connid].getVideoTracks().forEach(t => this._remoteAudioStreams[connid].removeTrack(t));
        this._remoteAudioStreams[connid].addTrack(event.track);
        if (this._remoteAudioPlayer != null) {
          this._remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = null;
          this._remoteAudioPlayer.srcObject = this._remoteAudioStreams[connid];
        }
        this._remoteAudioPlayer.load();
        debugger
      }
    }
    this.peers_con_ids[connid] = connid;
    this.peers_conns[connid] = this.connection;
    if (this._videoState == this.VideoStates.Camera || this._videoState == this.VideoStates.ScreenShare) {
      if (this._videoCamSSTrack) {
        this.AddUpdateAudioVideoSenders(this._videoCamSSTrack, this._rtpVideoSenders);
      }
    }
    return this.connection;
  }
```

Please let us know , how we can fix the above mentioned issue .

Comment: make one of these systems stun and turn server.

Comment: check your log, you will see all ice created. U need ensure the both side have srflx or relay